# Can a Mlflow model hosted databricks access db the pyfunc?

Tags: python, databricks, mlflow

I'm quite new to Mlflow, I am using MLFlow to wrap the model and serve on model serving. However some requirements I need are in a db that holds realtime data. For each call to the API I'll need data pulled from said db to properly send out an output. Is there a way to properly set that up? Currently calling the db within the pyfunc code, passing server certs

Comment: Sounds like you could use the [Online Feature Store](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/feature-store/online-feature-stores.html) where the real-time data is added to the online store and the pyfunc uses those features during inference.